# creating json or xml with mysql in php too slow

Tags: php, mysql, xml, json, performance

I am working on a project for a lecture at the university and I am searching for a solution for more than 2 weeks now, and I just can't get it right.

We have a project where we need to generate specific JSON or XML files to visualize them later with for example D3 or Sigma.

We have a mysql database and all the code is in Javascript (as you can see with the libraries) and we use pho to get the data from the database and to get it in the right format. Here is an example xml file I tried to create with php (it's a gexf-file for the visualization with Sigma, but it's just the same as xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gexf xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft" version="1.2">
<meta lastmodifieddate="2009-03-20">
    <creator>Gexf.net</creator>
    <description>A hello world! file</description>
</meta>
<graph mode="static" defaultedgetype="directed">
    <nodes>
        <node id="0" label="Hello" />
        <node id="1" label="Word" />
    </nodes>
    <edges>
        <edge id="0" source="0" target="1" />
    </edges>
</graph>
</gexf>
```

And Here is my php code where I tried to create the xml:

```
    <?php

set_time_limit(500000000);

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

class XmlWriter2 {
var $xml;
var $indent;
var $stack = array();
function XmlWriter($indent = '  ') {
    $this->indent = $indent;
    $this->xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'."\n";
}
function _indent() {
    for ($i = 0, $j = count($this->stack); $i < $j; $i++) {
        $this->xml .= $this->indent;
    }
}
function push($element, $attributes = array()) {
    $this->_indent();
    $this->xml .= '<'.$element;
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        $this->xml .= ' '.$key.'="'.htmlentities($value).'"';
    }
    $this->xml .= ">\n";
    $this->stack[] = $element;
}
function element($element, $content, $attributes = array()) {
    $this->_indent();
    $this->xml .= '<'.$element;
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        $this->xml .= ' '.$key.'="'.htmlentities($value).'"';
    }
   $this->xml .= '>'.htmlentities($content).'</'.$element.'>'."\n";
}
function emptyelement($element, $attributes = array()) {
    $this->_indent();
    $this->xml .= '<'.$element;
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        $this->xml .= ' '.$key.'="'.htmlentities($value).'"';
    }
    $this->xml .= " />\n";
}
function pop() {
    $element = array_pop($this->stack);
    $this->_indent();
    $this->xml .= "</$element>\n";
}
function getXml() {
    return $this->xml;
}
}
/*
$xml = new XmlWriter2();
$array = array(
array('monkey', 'banana', 'Jim'),
array('hamster', 'apples', 'Kola'),
array('turtle', 'beans', 'Berty'),
);
$xml->push('zoo');
foreach ($array as $animal) {
$xml->push('animal', array('species' => $animal[0]));
$xml->element('name', $animal[2]);
$xml->element('food', $animal[1]);
$xml->pop();
}
$xml->pop();
print $xml->getXml();
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zoo>
  <animal species="monkey">
    <name>Jim</name>
    <food>banana</food>
  </animal>
  <animal species="hamster">
    <name>Kola</name>
    <food>apples</food>
  </animal>
  <animal species="turtle">
    <name>Berty</name>
    <food>beans</food>
  </animal>
</zoo>
*/

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "manager") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("enrondata") or die(mysql_error()); 

$data1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT sId FROM mailToId WHERE date 
BETWEEN '01.06.2002' AND '30.06.2002' UNION SELECT DISTINCT rId FROM 
mailToId WHERE date BETWEEN '01.06.2002' AND '30.06.2002'") or die 
(mysql_error()); 

$data2 = mysql_query("SELECT sender, recipient, count(*) AS numMails 
FROM mailTo WHERE date BETWEEN '01.06.2002' AND '30.06.2002' GROUP 
BY sender, recipient") or die (mysql_error()); 

$users = array();
$id = 0;
while($tmpUsers = mysql_fetch_array($data1)){
$tmpArray['id'] = $tmpUsers['sId'];
$user = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=".$tmpUsers['sId']);
while($tmpUser = mysql_fetch_array($user)){
    $tmpArray['email'] = $tmpUser['email'];
}
array_push($users, $tmpArray);
}
$xml = new XmlWriter2();
$xml->push('gexf', array('xmlns' => 'http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft" version="1.2'));
$xml->push('meta', array('lastmodifieddate' => '2009-03-20'));
    $xml->element('creator', 'Gexf.net');
    $xml->element('description', 'A hello world! file');
$xml->pop();
$xml->push('graph', array('mode' => 'static', 'defaultedgetype' => 'directed'));
    $xml->push('nodes');
        for($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++){
            $xml->push('node', array('id' => $users['id'], 
'label' => $users['email']));$xml->pop();
    }
    $xml->pop();
    $xml->push('edges');
        while($tmp = mysql_fetch_array($data2)){
            $xml->push('edge', array('id' => id, 
'source' => $tmp['sender'], 'target' => $tmp['recipient'], 'weight' 
=> $tmp['numMails']));$xml->pop();
            $id++;
        }
    $xml->pop();
$xml->pop();
$xml->pop();
print $xml->getXml();
?>
```

And it works, the code is correct, but it takes hours. Really, even after 30min it is not finished doing all that. And I have no idea how to improve it and get it very fast. Or is there another possiblity to get the data from the mysql database in the right format without using php?

Please help me. My deadline is really close and I have no ideas and didn't find anything on the web that fits my problem.

Comment: is it the queries that are slow? test them one by one to see witch ones arethe slow ones, and then prepend the query whit "DESCRIBE " to get an analys of the querry

Comment: The first one takes 33,228 sec, the second one 7,363 sec and for each SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=... it takes 0,036 sec. So not half an hour?

Comment: In what way can describe help me there? And why llooking at the selects, because there no real way changing them, isn't there?

Comment: Does maybe anyone know another possibility to do this without using php?

Comment: the DESCRIBE can tell you if you have usable keys, if not adding a key can increase speed allot

Comment: I have primary keys and Index on all important columns. I already looked at this topic. I think the php code is just too slow, but I cannot impove it. I don't have any further ideas. So maybe I need an other solution for getting the data out of the database but regarding javascript.

Comment: can't see where in the code that it could eat up all that time, try mesuring what parts that take up all the time with http://se2.php.net/microtime, and add "break" to loops while doing it to just have them run once

Comment: Well I forgot to say, that I have about 500.000 rows in the database. Thats a lot, I know. But there are bigger databases that have way better performance. I will look at the times now...

Comment: Well, the second select with the group by already takes 104 sec when executing it in php... but I'm still working on the rest times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you doing over 500 000 querys, that a big overhead,
try just join in the email in the first query:

```
/* puggan added left join email */
$data1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT mailToId.sId, users.email FROM mailToId LEFT JOIN users ON (users.id = mailToId.sId) WHERE date BETWEEN '01.06.2002' AND '30.06.2002' UNION SELECT DISTINCT mailToId.rId, users.email FROM mailToId LEFT JOIN users ON (users.id = mailToId.rId) WHERE date BETWEEN '01.06.2002' AND '30.06.2002'") or die(mysql_error()); 

$data2 = mysql_query("SELECT sender, recipient, count(*) AS numMails FROM mailTo WHERE date BETWEEN '01.06.2002' AND '30.06.2002' GROUP BY sender, recipient") or die (mysql_error()); 

$users = array();
$id = 0;

while($tmpUsers = mysql_fetch_array($data1))
{
    $tmpArray['id'] = $tmpUsers['sId'];

    /* Puggan added: */
    $tmpArray['email'] = $tmpUsers['email'];

    // $user = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=".$tmpUsers['sId']);
    // while($tmpUser = mysql_fetch_array($user))
    // {
    //  $tmpArray['email'] = $tmpUser['email'];
    // }
    array_push($users, $tmpArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will also try this solution. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Thanks for the Select. It really is way faster. Can you maybe also tell me an alternative to the second select? Because it also takes long. I guess it's because of the "group by" but I can't image doing it different. Any idea?

Comment: the 2nd query is to simple to optimize the query, but you could add a index for the 3 columns in use (ate, sender, recipent), then it can read all data from a index in memory, insted from the harddrive, ther "DESCRIBE" of the query should then end up with one row having "useing index"

Comment: I solved it. It now only takes seconds to build the xml. Thanks a lot for all the help. This forum is great.

Comment: Hi @NadjaSadowski please consider accepting the answer by Puggan Se, this gives him credits! :-)